# Using mutliple predictors for text classification prediction through Multinomial Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification

My dataset contains only categorical variables. I have little problems using one categorical column to predict another of a dataframe, but I find it hard to wrap my head around how to use multiple columns/predictors to predict.

Let's say my dataset looks something like this:

```
ItemCode  ItemDescription  Kind_of_food 
273          Snicker         Chocolate 
230          Lay's Chips       Chips
274          KitKat          Chocolate
123          Gummy Bears       Candy
124          Oreo            Cookies 
123          Gummy Bears       Candy  
273          Snicker        Chocolate          

. . . x 1000000 rows.
```

If I were to predict Item Code using only Item Description, I first cleaned the dataset which is not shown below ( removing stopwords, apostrophes, etc.). I would then run it through train_test_split.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.metric import accuracy_score
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer()



x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['ItemDescription'], df['ItemCode'], , train_size = 100000, test_size = 30000, stratify = df['ItemCode']

stemmer = PorterStemmer()
analyzer = CountVectorizer().build_analyzer()

def stemmed(doc):
  return(stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

vect = CountVectorizer(ngram = range(2,2), max_features = 500, stop_words = stopWords, analyzer = stemmed_words, tokenizer = word_tokenizer) # stopWords is defined earlier and not showed in code, 

X_train = vect.fit_transform(x_train)
X_test = vect.transform(x_test)

multiNB = MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.2)
multiNB.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = multiNB.predict(X_test)

print("accuracy of test model is: ", accuracy_score(predicted, y_test))
```

This code works fine for 1 predictor but if I were to combine the Kind of Foods column through dummy variables.

```
dummies = pd.getDummies(df.Kind_of_food)
df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis = 'columns')
df = df.drop(['ItemCode', 'Cookies'], axis = 1)
```

I then make a new variable,

```
X = df[['ItemDescription', 'Cookies', 'Chips', 'Candy', 'Chocolate']]
```

and change train_test_split from:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['ItemDescription'], df['ItemCode'], , train_size = 100000, test_size = 30000, stratify = df['ItemCode']
```

to:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, train_size = 100000, test_size = 30000, stratify = Y)
```

I would get

```
Found input variables with inconsistent number of samples [3, 100000]
```

when I try to run the same code.

The code breaks on the multiNB.fit line when trying to fit x_train (100000, 3) and y_train (100000), How should I adjust my code and proceed?